# ASP.NET MVC database table getting null value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework-6, crud

I am creating a simple CRUD application using ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework, Data are being saved but the values are null when I check it from Database                                                             ..

Below I shared different class and files:-

EmployeeController class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ASP.NETMVCCRUD.Models;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;

namespace ASP.NETMVCCRUD.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Employee
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult GetData()
        {
            using (DBModel db = new DBModel())
            {
                List<Employee> emplist = db.Employees.ToList<Employee>();
                return Json(new { data = emplist }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult AddOrEdit(int id=0) {

            return View(new Employee());

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddOrEdit(Employee emp)
        {
            using (DBModel db = new DBModel())
            {
                db.Employees.Add(emp);

                db.SaveChanges();

                return Json(new {success = true, message="Saved Successfully",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });
            }

        }
    }
}
```

AddOrEdit.cshtml

```
@model ASP.NETMVCCRUD.Models.Employee
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddOrEdit", "Employee", FormMethod.Post, new {onsubmit="return SubmitForm(this)" }))
{ 

    @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.EmployeeID)
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Name, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Position, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.Position, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Position)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Office, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.Office, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Age, new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.Age, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

        @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Salary, new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
        @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.Salary, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn " />
    </div>
}
```

Employee.cs

```
namespace ASP.NETMVCCRUD.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Position { get; set; }
        public string Office { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Age { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Salary { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why this `htmlAttribute` `onsubmit="return SubmitForm(this)` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view contains a `@Html.HiddenFor()` for each property before the associated `EditorFor()` method. The `DefaultModelBinder` only binds the first matching name/value pair and ignores the others, so its the values of the hidden inputs (which are default values) that are being saved.

Remove all the `@Html.HiddenFor()` from your view and the edited values will be correctly bound.

As a side note, its unclear why your method is named `AddOrEdit` when all you are doing is adding new records.

Answer (score 0):

[HttpPost]

```
    public ActionResult AddOrEdit(Employee emp)
    {
        using (DBModel db = new DBModel())
        {
            db.Employees.Add(emp);
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch(DbEntityValidationException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            return Json(new { success = true, message = "Saved Succesfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
            
    }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome :) A small textual introduction/explanation might make this answer more helpful for others

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.